# how to display products in ascending order on oscommerce version2.3.3

Tags: php, sorting, oscommerce

In my Shopping cart, there is a product listing page.
I need to display the Last entered products first on that page (LIFO).
but currently page is displaying the first entered product first (FIFO).
i think that can be done changing sort field into Last entered product id.

Can anyone help on that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.
On index page we have to change the product listing query. On order by clause, add necessary field name with desc.
line number 158 to 163.

```
if ($column_list[$i] == 'PRODUCT_LIST_NAME') {
      $HTTP_GET_VARS['sort'] = $i+1 . 'd';
      $listing_sql .= " order by pd.products_name desc";
      break;
    }
```